# mapReduce to get desired output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Kindly point me in a direction to get my desired output

**Current outPut given:**

Albania 3607 ++ Country minPopulation

Albania 418495 ++ Country maxPopulation

**Desired Output**

country city minPopulation

country city maxPopulation

**Reducer Class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class Handson3Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,  Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String line = key.toString();
        String field[] = line.split(",");
        for (IntWritable value : values) {

            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
            minValue = Math.min(minValue, value.get());

        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(minValue));
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
    }

}
```

**Mapper class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class handson3Mapper extends  Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private static final int MISSING = 9999;
        
    @Override
    
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        int populationVal;
        String line = value.toString();
        String field[] = line.split(",");
        String country = field[4].substring(1, field[4].length()-1);
        String newString = country.concat(field[0].substring(1, field[0].length()-1));
        
        String population = field[9].substring(1, field[9].length()-1);
        String city = field[0].substring(1, field[0].length()-1);

        
        if (!population.matches(".*\\d.*") || population.equals("")||
                population.matches("([0-9].*)\\.([0-9].*)") ){
                return;
            }else{
                populationVal = Integer.parseInt(population);
                context.write(new Text(country),new IntWritable(populationVal));
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Runner Class:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class handsonJobRunner {
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception  {

        if(args.length !=2) {

            System.err.println("Usage: Handson3 <input path> <outputpath>");
            System.exit(-1);

        }
Job job = new Job();
        
        job.setJarByClass(handsonJobRunner.class);

        job.setJobName("Handson 3");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(handson3Mapper.class);

        job.setReducerClass(Handson3Reducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return success ? 0 : 1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        handsonJobRunner driver = new handsonJobRunner();
        driver.run(args);


    }

}
```

Thank you in advance, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send both city and population as value to reducer and at reducer select the city with max and min population for each country.

Your mapper would be like this:

```
public class Handson3Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private static final int MISSING = 9999;

    @Override

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int populationVal;
        String line = value.toString();
        String field[] = line.split(",");
        String country = field[4].substring(1, field[4].length() - 1);
        String newString = country.concat(field[0].substring(1, field[0].length() - 1));

        String population = field[9].substring(1, field[9].length() - 1);
        String city = field[0].substring(1, field[0].length() - 1);


        if (!population.matches(".*\\d.*") || population.equals("") ||
                population.matches("([0-9].*)\\.([0-9].*)")) {
            return;
        } else {
            populationVal = Integer.parseInt(population);
            context.write(new Text(country), new Text(city + "-" + populationVal));
        }
    }

}
```

And Your reducer should change to this one:

```
public class Handson3Reducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String maxPopulationCityName = "";
        String minPopulationCityName = "";
        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String line = key.toString();
        String field[] = line.split(",");
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            String[] array = value.toString().split("-");
            int population = Integer.valueOf(array[1]);
            if (population > maxValue) {
                maxPopulationCityName = array[0];
                maxValue = population;
            }
            if (population < minValue) {
                minPopulationCityName = array[0];
                minValue = population;
            }

        }
        context.write(new Text(key + " " + minPopulationCityName), new IntWritable(minValue));
        context.write(new Text(key + " " + maxPopulationCityName), new IntWritable(maxValue));
    }

}
```

Comment: Essentially,  I am trying to show the largest and the smallest city and their population for each country. When I do this, it shows every city with in a country with its population.

Comment: After reproducing you code I keep getting an error: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, any ideas why I am getting that error

Comment: Add this lines to the run method of Runner class: `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);`